# How to make a table of contents that links to the corresponding chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, chapters

I want that my table of content looks like this:

#### 1 Introduction

and if I click on the line, it should jump to the chapter.
But the chapter looks like this:

## Chapter 1

### Introduction

But I want it as

## 1 Introduction

.

My current LaTeX (relevant part, as recommended in the documentation):

```
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}\label{Introduction}
```

The enumeration of chapters should be automatically, so using `chapter*` is not an option.

Comment: is there a renewcommand ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The relevant part is precisely what you do not  show. In a `\documentclass{book}\begin{document} x \end{document}`  where `x` is your code, you will obtain  exactly what you want.  So, just don't do whatever else that you're doing to avoid the default output.

Comment: @Fran While I agree that a MWE would have been nice, I'm getting what OP claims to get, and not what they want.

Comment: @Teepeemm Oopps, I read too fast. I thought he wanted the "1 Introduction " in the ToC. `:(`

Answer (score 1):

Without a MWE  there are several options:

1. Do not use a `book` or `book`-like document class, but `article` or similar classes, and instead of `\chapter{}` use `\section{}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{foo} foo
\end{document}
```

The problem with this option could be that you really need all sectioning levels of a book, or the format of a book (front-matter with roman numeration, ToC in new page, blank pages before chapters, etc.). Otherwise, use this option!

2. Use `scrbook` without any settings.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{foo} foo
\end{document}
```

3. Use `memoir` with the `article` option.

Example:

```
    \documentclass[article]{memoir}
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{foo} foo
    \end{document}
```

4. Use te standard `book` and  customize the chapter style with the package `titlesec`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.7in}{20pt}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{foo} foo
\end{document}
```

Although the result is similar, note that `memoir` and `scrbook` are very rich classes with tons of own commands and  options, and this also matter, not only for chapter styles, so you should think twice before choose one of these or stay with the standard book.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `memoir` class, an extension of the `book` (report) class.

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir
\chapterstyle{section}
...
\chapter{Introduction}
...
```

It provides 6 different chapterstyles and the manual (`texdoc memoir`) explains how to make your own style.